# Contacts Cursor is always Null?

Tags: android, exception, cursor, contacts

I am getting data from phone databese.But always cursor getting `null`.I have also permission read contact. Can anybody help me?

```
//for get number and name from contacts
 c = getContentResolver().query(uri, new String[]{ 
                                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER,  
                                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE },
                                null, null, null);
```

My all code is here:

```
  @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
           if (data != null) {
                Uri uri = data.getData();

                if (uri != null) {
                    Cursor c = null;
                    try {
                        c = getContentResolver().query(uri, new String[]{ 
                                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER,  
                                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE },
                                null, null, null);

                        if (c != null && c.moveToFirst()) {
                            String number = c.getString(0);
                            int type = c.getInt(1);
                            Toast.makeText(this, type + ": " + number, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
                        }
                    } finally {
                        if (c != null) {
                            c.close();
                        }
                    }
                }
```

And `Exception` from logcat:

```
12-16 12:59:33.962: E/AndroidRuntime(20650): Caused by:   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid column data1
12-16 12:59:33.962: E/AndroidRuntime(20650): at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:167)
```

Comment: what is `uri`? can you post value of that?

Comment: Uri :content://com.android.contacts/contacts/lookup/2888i19d0e52809747dc1/374

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get `phoneNumber` with following code, use that:

```
  Cursor contact = getContentResolver().query(
                    ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
  if (contact.getCount() > 0) {
  contact.moveToFirst();

    do
    {
                String contactId = contact.getString(contact
                    .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));

        log.d("contactId is", contactId);

                     Cursor pCur = getContentResolver()
                            .query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                                    null,
                                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID
                                            + " = ?",
                                    new String[] { contactId }, null);
                if (pCur.getCount() > 0){
                    pCur.moveToFirst();
                    do {
                        String number = pCur
                                .getString(pCur
                                        .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                            log.d("number is",number);

                    } while (pCur.moveToNext());
    }
            }
    while(contact.moveToNext());
   }
```

Comment: first test this,if worked for you then yes,delete your cursor ,See my Edt

Comment: I am getting this error 12-16 14:02:38.300: E/AndroidRuntime(2142): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: the bind value at index 1 is null

Comment: did you test the Edit Code? where you test this? did you have contact in your device?

Comment: Yes yes i tested.HTC one and HTC Desire .I have contactlist.I am seeing contactlist.When i picked one of them after the cursor query i am getting this error

Comment: this code is worked for me, maybe problem is some where else, log the value of `cantactId` and `PhoneNumber` and find out where your program is crash

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43255/discussion-between-shayan-pourvatan-and-duyguk)